# Using my VPS as a proxy server

Tags: windows, proxy, vps, windows-phone

I have a VPS which is running windows XP SP3 on it. I want to connect from my home PC to the internet through it.

How can I configure a private proxy for this purpose? (sorry I couldn't find a way for windows by searching)

**Update:** I like to connect to the internet throw that VPS in my **Windows Phone 8** too. I see I just can insert username, password, ip address and port in settings area. If I could set it up to run it on WP8, that will be perfect.

Comment: What operating system do you run on your home PC?

Comment: windows 8, and I like to use it with my windows phone 8 too.